Convergence of random sequence$X_n$ specified by $X_n\leq aX_{n-1}$ with probability $1$ and $X_n\leq bX_{n-1}$ with probability $p$
I have a sequence of strictly positive numbers, $x_n$, and suppose I know deterministically $x_1=\alpha$. But $x_n\leq ax_{n-1}$ with probability $1$ and $x_n\leq bx_{n-1}$ with probability $p$. Here, $a>b>0$.

I want to know if I should consider the sequence $x_n$ as a sequence of random numbers or as a deterministic sequence. My feeling is: it should be a sequence of random variables because the rate of growth is governed by randomness. Is that correct?
If I consider it as a random sequence $X_n$, can I model it as follows?
Let $Z_n$ be a sequence if iid random variables with $Pr[Z_n\leq b]=p$, $Pr[b<Z_n\leq a]=1-p$.

$X_n\leq Z_n X_{n-1}, \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$?

If I am allowed to model it as in (2) and if I set $a=1$, $b=1/2$, I think I can show $X_n$ converges almost surely. Is that true? If so, how can I indicate the rate of convergence?

Any thoughts or any help will be greatly appreciated. This is not a HW problem. I am just trying to model something in real life.

@Henry Thank you for pointing that out. I will edit the question.

@Henry Does my question make sense now?

That looks more consistent now.

@Henry Thank you so much. So I should really be thinking of $x_n$ as a random sequence, right?


$x_n$ cannot be deterministic as it needs to satisfy the following probabilistic condition:


$x_n\leq ax_{n-1}$ with probability $1$ and $x_n\leq bx_{n-1}$ with probability $p$.


Your construction is correct. For example, assume that $Z_1,Z_2, \dots$ are iid and have a mixed distribution that takes $U(0,b)$ with probability $p$ and $U(b,a)$ with probability $1-p$. Then, the sequence $X_1,X_2, \dots$ defined recursively as follows:$$X_n=Z_i X_{n-1}, n=1,2, \dots \tag{1}$$
satisfies the given conditions.

Each $X_n$ in (1) is explicitly given by $$X_n=\alpha \prod_{i=1}^n Z_i, n=1,2, \dots. \tag{2}$$
It can be shown that $X_n$ almost surely converges to zero and infinity if $\mathbb E \left (\log(Z_i) \right )<0$ (holds when $a,b<1$) and $\mathbb E \left (\log(Z_i) \right )>0$ (holds when $a,b>1$ are sufficiently large), respectively (the expectation needs to be calculated). To prove this, let us defin $Y_i=\log(Z_i).$ Then, (2) can be written as $$X_n= \alpha \exp \left[ n \left( \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i \right)
 \right] \to 0 (\infty) \,\, \text{a.s.}$$ where the convergence follows from the continuity of $e^x$ and the SLLN: $$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i \to \mathbb E \left (\log(Z_i) \right )< (>) \,\, 0 \,\, \text{a.s.}$$

Let  $\mathbb E \left (Z_i\right )<1$, which also implies  $\mathbb E \left (\log(Z_i) \right )<0$ by Jensen inequlity, and thus from point 3 $X_n$ tends to $0$ a.s. Then, by Markov inequality for any $\epsilon>0$, $$ \mathbb P \left (X_n \ge \epsilon\right ) \le \frac{\alpha\left (\mathbb E \left (Z_i\right ) \right )^n}{\epsilon}.$$ Hence, when $\frac{\epsilon\delta}{\alpha}<1$ (implied if $\epsilon <\alpha$), for $$n \ge \frac{\log \epsilon + \log \delta- \log \alpha}{\log \mathbb E \left (Z_i\right )}$$ we have $$\mathbb P \left (X_n < \epsilon\right ) \ge 1-\delta.$$ A similar bound can be obtained whenever $\mathbb E \left (\frac{1}{Z_i}\right )<1$, which also implies  $\mathbb E \left (\log(Z_i) \right )>0$ by Jensen inequlity, and thus $X_n$ tends to $\infty$ a.s.



Thank you for your answer. Could you please answer the last part of the question as well? How can I characterize the convergence rate?

@curiosity You are welcome! What type of rate analysis do you need? Could you give more details about your application?

What can I say about $x_n$ before $n$ gets to infinity? For example, can I say something like "If I want $x_n$ to be less than $0.05$ with probability $0.9$ (90% chance), I should go to $n\geq N$ iteration. If I know a fixed $x$ and a fixed probability, can I say what $N$ would do the trick? Thank you so much. I really appreciate your help.

Okay I now see what you want. I will add some results that can help you.

Thank you so much. I really appreciate your generosity with your time.

@curiosity please check the new point 4.

This is beautiful. Thank you so much. Wishing you to have an amazing rest of the weekend. I know I will, thanks to you.

@curiosity glad it's helpful, you too!

$x_n$ can be non-random; for example, let
$$
x_n=\alpha \gamma^n
$$
where $\gamma=\min(a,b)$ is not random.
Here's another example, where the sequence is random. Take
$$
a=1,\quad b=\frac12.
$$
Let
$$
x_n=\alpha\xi_1\xi_2\dots\xi_n
$$
where $\xi_i$s are i.i.d., with
$$
\mathbb{P}(\xi=1)=\mathbb{P}\left(\xi=\frac12\right)=\frac12=:p.
$$
Then the conditions are verified.

Thanks so much for your answer but could you please help me understand it better? How does your sequence model the fact that $x_n\leq b x_{n-1}$ with probability $p$?

It does not "model" this fact, it satisfies the conditions you wrote. So with probability $p$, $x_n\le b x_{n-1}$; as you did not specify what happens otherwise, the same inequality is still allowed to hold.

Thank you for your explanation. So I think, your sequence is one realization among possible sequences. That's why I am thinking of it as a random sequence because we don't know exactly how the later terms will evolve. Is it incorrect to think that way? Sorry about the really naive question and I appreciate your patience.

There can be of course different sequences, including random which satisfy your condition.

Surely this has $\Pr(x_n\leq bx_{n-1})=1\neq p$?

@EspeciallyLime, yes, in my example; but there's a random example as well (please see the answer)
